# Table with total per month

Tags: views

I created a table with operations sorted by date. How to display a second array with the total transaction per month ?

I want to show by example the total in September 2016, the total amount of August 2016 ...

Table should display one line per month with the total amount of transactions.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The same month are not grouped :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to use  [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator)

See Example here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2361413
It says a similar thing would work(aggregate and group by column).

God Bless.

Comment: thank you, but it is doable with "use aggregation: yes" and using filter criteria month ?

Comment: @Mathieu I'm not sure what else you could try..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert your date field in a [PHP format](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) to display 'month YEAR' (like *august 2016*) and then use grouping on the month + sum on the money field to aggregate on the month. 
As Sammy7 said [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) might give you an handy option.

Comment: I've updated the question. I do not want to use complementary modules. I changed the date format, but I can not regrouler month with the sum